# How can I iterate over a string by runes in Go?

Tags: string, loops, go, rune

I wanted to this:

```
for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
    dosomethingwithrune(str[i]) // takes a rune
}
```

But it turns out that `str[i]` has type `byte` (`uint8`) rather than `rune`.

How can I iterate over the string by runes rather than bytes?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

See this example from [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for) :

```
for pos, char := range "日本語" {
    fmt.Printf("character %c starts at byte position %d\n", char, pos)
}
```

This prints :

```
character 日 starts at byte position 0
character 本 starts at byte position 3
character 語 starts at byte position 6
```

> For strings, the range does more work for you, breaking out individual
>   Unicode code points by parsing the UTF-8.

Answer (score 45):

To mirror an example given at [golang.org](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library), Go allows you to easily convert a string to a slice of runes and then iterate over that, just like you wanted to originally:

```
runes := []rune("Hello, 世界")
for i := 0; i < len(runes) ; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("Rune %v is '%c'\n", i, runes[i])
}
```

Of course, we could also use a range operator like in the other examples here, but this more closely follows your original syntax. In any case, this will output:

```
Rune 0 is 'H'
Rune 1 is 'e'
Rune 2 is 'l'
Rune 3 is 'l'
Rune 4 is 'o'
Rune 5 is ','
Rune 6 is ' '
Rune 7 is '世'
Rune 8 is '界'
```

Note that since the `rune` type is an alias for `int32`, we must use `%c` instead of the usual `%v` in the `Printf` statement, or we will see the integer representation of the Unicode code point (see [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/11)).

Answer (score 21):

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        for i, rune := range "Hello, 世界" {
                fmt.Printf("%d: %c\n", i, rune)
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/VY9wRxx0lr)

---

Output:

```
0: H
1: e
2: l
3: l
4: o
5: ,
6:  
7: 世
10: 界
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, a code example that doesn't uses `fmt` package:

```golang
package main

func main() {
    for _, rune := range "Hello, 世界" {
        println(string(rune))
    }
}
```

In the loop, the variable `r` represents the current `rune` being iterated over. We convert it to a string using the `string()` function before printing it to the console.

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2wjQfJjO2fh)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [doc](https://go.dev/blog/strings).

`rune` basically is an alias for `int32` type:

```
type rune = int32
```

Literal strings in Go are being encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) format, which allows to store Unicode codes corresponding to the characters from Unicode [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

```
0xxxxxxx                              unicode codes 0−127
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx                     128−2047
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx            2048−65535
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx   65536−0x10ffff
```

as you can see such encoding takes 1-4 bytes per character, and that is why we have `rune = int32` (4 bytes) here to accommodate the worst-case scenario when we need 4 bytes to encode Unicode character code.

From Unicode [table](https://www.charset.org/utf-8) you can see that if your `string` has only alphanumeric (ASCII characters) then the number of runes in your `string` would be equal to the number of bytes, as such ASCII characters take just 1 byte to be encoded. But it is not true when you use non-ASCII characters:

```
import "unicode/utf8"

func countRunes() {
    s := "Hello, 世界"
    fmt.Println(len(s)) // "13" - bytes
    fmt.Println(utf8.RuneCountInString(s)) // "9" - runes characters
}
```

---

##### Strings are built from bytes so indexing them yields bytes and not characters, to access characters (runes) you can use the options below:

1. Language built-in way to iterate over runes:

```golang
for i, r := range "Hello, 世界" {
    fmt.Printf("%d\t%q\t%d\n", i, r, r)
}
```

2. By getting an array of runes from `string`:

```
runes := []rune("Hello, 世界")
for i := 0; i < len(runes) ; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("Rune : '%c'\n", runes[i])
}
```

3. By using the standard library package `utf8`:

```
for i := 0; i < len(s); {
    r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s[i:])
    fmt.Printf("%d\t%c\n", i, r)
    i += size
}
```